# Could not find firebase-messaging.jar - Android Build Error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this build error.

> Could not find firebase-messaging.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2). Searched in the
>   following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/15.0.2/firebase-messaging-15.0.2.jar

I have attached the build.gradle code below. Please check. I am not able to get solution for this on stackoverflow

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id : "65f11821-XXXXXX-4ec4-9e41-XXXXXXXX",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "XXXXX"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // applovin
    implementation project(':unity-ads')
    //unity ads
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //compile 'com.github.cooltechworks:ScratchView:v1.1'//not used
    implementation 'com.jackpocket:scratchoff:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.33.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.7.0.1@jar'
    //compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:2.1.1.0' //not used
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
    //implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    //get server time
    //compile 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:2.0'
    //compile 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library:2.0' // not used
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    //implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.9.1]'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.7.0-javadoc.jar')
    implementation files('libs/applovin-sdk-7.7.0.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Comment: @Murwa ..... Not even getting the solution on stackoverflow :P

Comment: Did you find the solution? If yes please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moving google() on top of jcenter() worked for me in the build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, the error is shown in the java file in the import statements but the project complies and runs. 
I tried clean build, invalidate cache and restart and everything else but still didn't work.

Comment: @bhaskar if the error is in import statement then you might not have added some dependency in build.gradle

Comment: if it was the case it should not have compiled as well, but it compiles and runs but shows error in import.

Comment: @bhaskar better post the error log + code or ask the question on stackoverflow